# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, sql-insert

Estou tentando inserir uns valores no banco, porém ta sempre dando exceção.

A minha classe que insere no banco:

```java
private String email;
private int codigo;

private Button btnOkay;
private Button btnCancelar;
private EditText codigoConfirmaCadastro;
private TextView reenviarEmail;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_confirma_cadastro);

    try {
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        if (intent != null) {
            email = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL);
        }

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        final String nome = extras.getString("nome");
        final String cpf = extras.getString("cpf");
        final String data = extras.getString("data");
        final String senha = extras.getString("senha");


        enviaEmailConfirmacao();

        btnOkay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_okayConfirmaCadastro);
        btnCancelar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_cancelarConfirmaCadastro);
        codigoConfirmaCadastro = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.codigo_confirmaCadastro);
        reenviarEmail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.reenviar_email);


        btnOkay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    String text = codigoConfirmaCadastro.getText().toString();
                    text.trim();
                    boolean isInserted;
                    if(text.isEmpty()) {
                        throw new Exception("Informe o código.");
                    }

                    int cod = Integer.parseInt(text);

                    if (cod != codigo) {
                        throw new Exception("Informe o código correto");
                    } else {

                        isInserted = PrincipalActivity.myDb.cadastrarUsuario(nome, email, senha, cpf, data);

                        if (isInserted == true) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ConfirmaCadastroActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            throw new Exception("Houve algúm erro ao cadastrar o usuário");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(ConfirmaCadastroActivity.this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }
        });

        btnCancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        reenviarEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                enviaEmailConfirmacao();
                Toast.makeText(ConfirmaCadastroActivity.this, "E-mail enviado, se o problema persistir, verifique o e-mail informado",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Classe do banco:

```java
public static final String NOME_BANCO = "banco.db";
public static final int VERSION = 5;

public static final String tabela_produto = "produto", nome_produto = "nome_produto", cod_produto = "cod_produto",
categoria = "categoria", peso = "peso", preco = "preco";
public static final String tabela_usuario = "usuario", nome_usu = "nome_usu", email = "email", senha = "senha",
cpf = "cpf", dt_nasc = "dt_nasc";
public static final String tabela_carrinho = "carrinho", nome_produto_carrinho = "nome_produto_carrinho",
cod_produto_carrinho = "cod_produto_carrinho", categoria_carrinho = "categoria_carrinho", peso_carrinho = "peso_carrinho",
preco_carrinho = "preco_carrinho", qtd_carrinho = "qtd_carrinho";
public static final String tabela_lista = "lista", nome_produto_lista = "nome_produto_lista";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, NOME_BANCO, null, VERSION);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + tabela_produto + " (" +
            nome_produto + " text, " +
            cod_produto + " text primary key, " +
            categoria + " text, " +
            peso + " text, " +
            preco + " integer)");


    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + tabela_usuario + " (" +
            nome_usu + " text, " +
            email + " text, " +
            senha + " text, " +
            cpf + " text primary key, " +
            dt_nasc + " date)");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + tabela_carrinho  + " (" +
            nome_produto_carrinho + " text, " +
            cod_produto_carrinho + " text primary key, " +
            categoria_carrinho + " text, " +
            peso_carrinho + " text, " +
            preco_carrinho + " integer)");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + tabela_lista + " (" +
            nome_produto_lista + " text)");



}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + tabela_produto);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + tabela_usuario);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + tabela_carrinho);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + tabela_lista);
    onCreate(db);
    db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + tabela_carrinho + " ADD COLUMN " + qtd_carrinho + " integer");

}

public boolean inserirProduto(String nome_produto1, String cod_produto1, String categoria1, String peso1, int preco1) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(nome_produto, nome_produto1);
    contentValues.put(cod_produto, cod_produto1);
    contentValues.put(categoria, categoria1);
    contentValues.put(peso, peso1);
    contentValues.put(preco, preco1);

    long result = db.insert(tabela_produto, null, contentValues);

    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public Cursor carregaDados() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tabela_produto, null);
    return res;
}

public Cursor carregaDadoPorCodigo(String scanCodigo) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor res;
    String[] campos = {nome_produto, cod_produto, categoria, peso, preco};
    String where = cod_produto + " = " + scanCodigo;

    res = db.query(tabela_produto, campos, where, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (res != null) {
        res.moveToFirst();
    }
    db.close();
    return res;
}


public Cursor carregaDadosCarrinho() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tabela_carrinho, null);
    return res;
}


public Integer deletaTudo() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    return db.delete(tabela_produto, null, null) + db.delete(tabela_carrinho, null, null);
}

public boolean inserirProdutoCarrinho(String nome_produto1, String cod_produto1, String categoria1, String peso1,
                                      int preco1, int qtd) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(nome_produto_carrinho, nome_produto1);
    contentValues.put(cod_produto_carrinho, cod_produto1);
    contentValues.put(categoria_carrinho, categoria1);
    contentValues.put(peso_carrinho, peso1);
    contentValues.put(preco_carrinho, preco1);
    contentValues.put(qtd_carrinho, qtd);

    long result = db.insert(tabela_carrinho, null, contentValues);

    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public boolean alteraQTD(String codigo, int quantidade) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues valores;

    valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put(qtd_carrinho, quantidade);

    db.update(tabela_carrinho, valores, cod_produto_carrinho + " = ?", new String[] {codigo});
    db.close();

    return true;
}

public boolean cadastrarUsuario(String nome_usu1, String email1, String senha1, String cpf1, String dt_nasc1) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put(nome_usu, nome_usu1);
    valores.put(email, email1);
    valores.put(senha, senha1);
    valores.put(cpf, cpf1);
    valores.put(dt_nasc, dt_nasc1);

    long resultado = db.insert(tabela_usuario, null, valores);

    if(resultado == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public Cursor carregaUsuario(String email1, String senha1) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor res;
    String[] campos = {email, senha};
    String where = email + " = " + email1 + " AND " + senha + " = " + senha1;

    res = db.query(tabela_usuario, campos, where, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (res != null) {
        res.moveToFirst();
    }
    db.close();
    return res;
}

public Cursor carregaUsuarioEmail(String email1) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor res;
    String[] campos = {nome_usu, email, senha, cpf};
    String where = email + " = " + email1;

    res = db.query(tabela_usuario, campos, where, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (res != null) {
        res.moveToFirst();
    }
    db.close();
    return res;
}
```

Me ajudem por favor
Esse é o erro:

> 06-03 01:56:20.536 31451-31451/com.example.myapplicationbanco
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com.example.myapplicationbanco, PID: 31451
>                                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean
>   com.example.myapplicationbanco.DatabaseHelper.cadastrarUsuario(java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                       at
>   com.example.myapplicationbanco.ConfirmaCadastroActivity$1.onClick(ConfirmaCadastroActivity.java:69)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

A principalActivity:

```java
public class PrincipalActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    public static DatabaseHelper myDb;
    private ListView catalogoCategoriaList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        myDb.inserirProduto("Feijão", "48579", "Alimentos", "1", 3);
        myDb.inserirProduto("Arroz", "666777", "Alimentos", "1", 2);
        myDb.inserirProduto("Macarrão", "4823421", "Alimentos", "0.5", 2);
        myDb.inserirProduto("Vodka", "216584", "Bebidas", "1", 8);
        myDb.inserirProduto("Coca-cola", "498437", "Bebidas", "2,5", 7);
        myDb.inserirProduto("Fraldas", "798458", "Bebes", "2", 30);
        myDb.inserirProduto("Molho-Shoyo", "242526", "Temperos", "0.25", 2);
        myDb.inserirProduto("Banana", "161719", "Frutas", "1", 4);


        catalogoCategoriaList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_categoria);


        ArrayAdapter<String> adpDados;

        final ArrayList<String> categorias = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor = myDb.carregaDados();

        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            if (!categorias.contains(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.categoria)))) {
                categorias.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.categoria)));
            }
        }

        adpDados = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, categorias);
        catalogoCategoriaList.setAdapter(adpDados);
        catalogoCategoriaList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProdutosCatalogoActivity.class);
                    String categoria1 = categorias.get(position);
                    intent.putExtra("categoria1", categoria1);
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.principal, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_scan) {
            IntentIntegrator scan = new IntentIntegrator(this);
            scan.initiateScan();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_carrinho) {

            Intent it = new Intent(this, CarrinhoActivity.class);
            startActivity(it);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_terminar) {

            myDb.deletaTudo();
            finish();

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        IntentResult resultado = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if(resultado != null) {
            final String scanCodigo = resultado.getContents();

            final Cursor res = myDb.carregaDadoPorCodigo(scanCodigo);



                AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
                ad.setTitle("Deseja adicionar ao carrinho?");
                ad.setMessage("Nome: " + res.getString(res.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.nome_produto)) + "\n"
                            +"Código: " + res.getString(res.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.cod_produto)) + "\n"
                            +"Categoria: " + res.getString(res.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.categoria)) + "\n"
                            +"Peso: " + res.getString(res.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.peso)) + "\n"
                            + "Preço: " + res.getString(res.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.preco)));
                ad.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        int qtd = 1;

                       boolean isInserted = myDb.inserirProdutoCarrinho(res.getString(res.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.nome_produto)),
                                res.getString(res.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.cod_produto)),
                                res.getString(res.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.categoria)),
                                res.getString(res.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.peso)),
                                Integer.parseInt(res.getString(res.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.preco))), qtd);

                        if (isInserted == true) {
                            Toast.makeText(PrincipalActivity.this, "Produto adicionado ao carrinho.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(PrincipalActivity.this, "Este Produto já existe no seu carrinho", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                    }
                });
                ad.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Nâo", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(PrincipalActivity.this, "Produto não adicionado ao carrinho.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


                ad.show();


        } if(resultado == null) {
            Toast.makeText(PrincipalActivity.this, "Desculpe, nenhum código de barras encontrado.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: aparentemente PrincipalActivity.myDb não está instanciado (está null) tem como postar o código de PrincipalActivity?

Comment: Pronto, a principalActivity ta aí. Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - É importante dar myDB.close(), se não a conexão com o banco fica aberta para sempre, custando ao aparelho
2 - Não tenha medo de instanciar o banco mais de uma vez. O null pointer está aparecendo por que você está se referenciando ao myDB da outra activity que é estaticamente nulo. O ideal é você instanciar o banco sempre que precisar usa-lo e logo depois dar um db.close().

Logo, ao invés de escrever:

```
else {

isInserted = PrincipalActivity.myDb.cadastrarUsuario(nome, email, senha, cpf, data);
```

Escreva:

```
else {
DatabaseHelper mydb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
isInserted = myDb.cadastrarUsuario(nome, email, senha, cpf, data);
myDb.close();
```

Comment: Obrigado. Ajudou bastante! Obrigado mesmo!

Comment: Mas agora eu to tendo problema com o cursor que chama o carregaUsuario e o carregaUsuarioEmail. Não da erro nenhum, ele simplesmente não retorna nada. Já dei ´db.close();´ tanto nos metodos da DatabaseHelper quanto nas classes que chama os metodos, e ainda sim da esse problema. A query não retorna